# Why getStaticProps giving error of "Failed to load SWC binary for win32/x64"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using getStaticProps() in a Next.js app but when I run the app it gives ERROR:-

```
warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-x64-gnu, but it was not installed
warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc, but an error occurred: The specified 
module could not be found.
\\?\D:\tasks\next-js\node_modules\@next\swc-win32-x64-msvc\next-swc.win32-x64-msvc.node
error - Failed to load SWC binary for win32/x64, see more info here: 
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! next-js@0.1.0 dev: `next dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
```

I tried all methods like uninstalling node_module, package-lock and reinstalling it. I tried adding .babelrc file, also added swcMinify: false in next.config but nothing works.
**When I use useEffect instead of getStaticProps then it works fine.**
Here is the getStaticProps function:-

```
export const getStaticProps = async () =>{

const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
const data = await res.json();

return{
    props: {
        data,
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: I just had this same issue. The error occurs even if you comment our the `getStaticProps` export too, which is even more bizarre.

Comment: I was runnign Next.js 12.1.6 and React 18. Downgraded to Nextjs 12.1.0 and React 17 and it worked. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appears when running `next@12.1.6` and happens even if your `.babelrc` file and `next.config.js` files are configured to not load swc.

If you downgrade to `next@12.1.0`, the swc binary load error should go away.